# Dynamic margin value using mixins

Tags: css, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I want to add dynamic margins to elements for that I have written following SCSS code

```
    @function get-spacing($keys...) {
    $list: ();

    @for $i from 1 through length($keys) {
        $key: nth($keys, $i);

        @if map-has-key($global-spacing, $key) {
            @if length($keys) == 1 {
                $list: map-get($global-spacing, $key) * 1px;
            }
            @else {
                $list: append($list, map-get($global-spacing, $key) * 1px, space);
            }
        }
        @else {
            @error '#{$key} does not exist in the $global-spacing map.  Allowed values are #{$global-spacing}.';
            @return null;
        }
    }

    @return $list;
}


// margin and padding values array
$space-values : (
  0,
  3,
  5,
  10,
  15,
  20,
  25,
  30,
  35,
  40,
  45,
  50,
  auto
) !default;

// margin and padding shorthands
$space-prefixes : (
  u-p  : padding,
  u-pt : padding-top,
  u-pr : padding-right,
  u-pb : padding-bottom,
  u-pl : padding-left,
  u-m  : margin,
  u-mt : margin-top,
  u-mr : margin-right,
  u-mb : margin-bottom,
  u-ml : margin-left,
  u-ml-auto : margin-left
) !default;

@mixin make-spaces() {
  @each $attr-short, $attr-long in $space-prefixes { 
    @each $value in $space-values {
      .#{$attr-short}-#{$value} {
        #{$attr-long}: #{$value}#{'px'};
      }
    }
  }
}

@include make-spaces();
```

My problem is if I give class .u-ml-3 then its applying correctly but if I give class .u-ml-auto then margin-left:auto not taking. Value in pixel format is taking correctly but when I want to apply margin auto then its not applying properly. Please help me in this. Thanks

Comment: Write your values as 0px, 3px, 5px, 10px etc. And don't multiply your values by 1px, as Chandra's answer points out. It will only add px value after the auto value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@function get-spacing($keys...) {
    $list: ();

    @for $i from 1 through length($keys) {
        $key: nth($keys, $i);

        @if map-has-key($global-spacing, $key) {
            @if length($keys) == 1 {
                $list: map-get($global-spacing, $key) * 1px;
            }
            @else {
                $list: append($list, map-get($global-spacing, $key) * 1px, space);
            }
        }
        @else {
            @error '#{$key} does not exist in the $global-spacing map.  Allowed values are #{$global-spacing}.';
            @return null;
        }
    }

    @return $list;
}


// margin and padding values array
$space-values : (
  0,
  3,
  5,
  10,
  15,
  20,
  25,
  30,
  35,
  40,
  45,
  50,
  auto
) !default;

// margin and padding shorthands
$space-prefixes : (
  u-p  : padding,
  u-pt : padding-top,
  u-pr : padding-right,
  u-pb : padding-bottom,
  u-pl : padding-left,
  u-m  : margin,
  u-mt : margin-top,
  u-mr : margin-right,
  u-mb : margin-bottom,
  u-ml : margin-left,
  u-ml-auto : margin-left
) !default;

@mixin make-spaces() {
  @each $attr-short, $attr-long in $space-prefixes { 
    @each $value in $space-values {
      .#{$attr-short}-#{$value} {
        @if $value == 'auto'{ /*add the @if loop*/
          #{$attr-long}:#{$value};
        }
        @else{
        #{$attr-long}: #{$value}#{'px'};
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@include make-spaces();
```

because the css output for

```
.u-ml-auto {
  margin-left: autopx; //autopx is invalid css rule
}
```